# c# Is there a way to determine if an object value is a base type like ints and strings or like class or structs

Tags: c#, object, serialization

I want to make a serializer and to do this I have to check if the current object's type can hold multiple values. (What I mean by base type are Strings and Ints)

I know there are a lot of great serializers out on the internet but I am doing this as a challenge and most of them don't have the features I want

I guess ints and strings are also classes but what I want is like this:

```cs
bool CheckIfBaseType(object value)  { return //check }
```

I don't think there is a proper way to do this instead of saving each base type in an array

**Edit:**

I think I can use reflection to check if there are any public variables but is there a better way to do this?

**Edit 2:**

Ok, I am going to try to explain it a bit more,
so what I really want is a function that can detect if a value can hold another value so I can check the child value

Algorithmic explanation:

```
    if(objectCanHoldValues(value))
    {
        //switch the target object to the child object and check if 
        it can hold a value (this part is done)
    }
```

please do not dislike when I say your solution doesn't work.
I am really new to the Stack overflow if I make a mistake I am sorry

Comment: "What I mean by base type are Strings and Ints" - *just* those types? What about other integer types, such as UInt32 or Int64? What about DateTime, Guid etc? You really need to define the criteria *absolutely precisely* or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: "if the current object's type can hold multiple values" - what does this mean? Can you give examples?

Comment: @JonSkeet well of course there are a ton of types I just didn't want to count them in the post

or else you would have to read this mess: "byte sbyte short ushort int uint object long ulong float double decimal char string bool "

Comment: So were we meant to *guess* that you would include `decimal` and `object` in a list of "like ints and strings"? Again, you really need to clarify *exactly* what you mean - what is the defining quality you're interested in here? If you can't specify it precisely, you won't be able to write code specifying it either.

Comment: Outside what Klaus and Jon already said: I smell an x-y here. Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for?

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{

    private static HashSet<Type> otherScalarTypes = new HashSet<Type>
    {
        typeof(string), typeof(Guid), typeof(DateTime),
        typeof(DateTimeOffset)
    };

    public static bool IsScalar(this Type type)
    {
        return type.IsPrimitive || otherScalarTypes.Contains(type);
    }
}
```

Note that Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single are primitive types.

Then you can check if it is a "base type":

```
if (obj.GetType().IsScalar()) 
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! this is absolutely what I wanted even dough it uses a list to determine

Answer (score 0):

Use .Net Reflection to check IsPrimitive, IsArray, or for other types

[image]